# Chrome malicious file warning

Tags: google-chrome, download

I have .exe file that can be downloaded from my website but in Chrome I am getting the malicious file warning.

I have already added the site to the Google Webmaster Tools and it seems already reviewed but still I am getting the malicious warning when I am trying to download the exe file.

Is there any definite solution on this issue since I dont see accepted answer on the previous postings?

Is there any change that my exe is not signed? Or a problem in the sitemap while submitting it in the Google Webmaster tools?

Comment: Is your file self signed?

Comment: Hi Matthew, the file is not signed. Should I sign it in order to bypass the warning?

Comment: Well this should be the standard method of doing things, but Google seem a little hazy on the matter. There doesn't seem to be an answer provided in their own forums, but some suggestions in there might help https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r-9JQIboUmc. I suggest you don't post questions on multiple exchange sites. They don't really like it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didnt know that! :) So, as far I understand there is no definite answer for this - most probably I have to sign my executable and wish me good luck... :)

Comment: If Chrome is saying its a malicious file its either a false postive and should be reported to Google or its actually malicious.  Even if you were to sign the file, it wouldn't change the fact, the signature of the file is defined as being malicious.

Comment: Do you know where I can report it? From WebMaster tools I cannot find any submission.

Comment: Just an update when the .exe file is compressed in a zip file, the malicious warning still appears. On the other hand, when the compressed file has rar extension, the malicious warning does not appear anymore. So I will go for the second option. Thanks!